# Need help evaluating the efficiency of code for printing a pyramid made with #'s and spaces

Tags: c, cs50

A problem from Harvard's CS50x course wants an input for height between 1 and 8. With this height, the output should print a pyramid made of spaces and #'s.

[example pyramid](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ugxgQ.png)

```
#include <cs50.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
    int height = 0;
    do
    {
        // prompt for pos int between 1-8
        height = get_int("Height? ");
    }
    while (height < 1 || height > 8);

    for (int row = 0; row < height; row++)
    {
        // print left spaces
        for (int j = height - row; j > 1; j--)
        {
            printf(" ");
        }

        // print left #
        for (int i = row; i >= 0; i--)
        {
            printf("#");
        }

        // print gap
        printf("  ");

        // print right #
        for (int z = row; z >= 0; z--)
        {
            printf("#");
        }

        // print new line
        printf("\n");
    }
}
```

I passed all of the test cases but I was wondering if there was a way to solve this problem using less lines of code.

Comment: Besides the two `#include` lines, you can do it in one line of code: `int main(void) { int height; do { height = get_int("Height? "); } while (height < 1 || 8 < height); for (int row = 1; row <= height; row++) printf("%*s%.*s  %.*s\n", height-row, "", row, "########", row, "########"); }`. Is that what you want? Fewer lines of code is not a good metric.

Comment: Code review questions are off topic here. You should delete this and ask, instead, on https://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: @EricPostpischil I think he really means "simpler code", not just counting lines.

Comment: @Barmar: That is what I provided, simpler code. Two nominal loops instead of six. And all on one line, as a bonus.

Comment: If you want to answer, post it as a real answer, not in a comment. There's no way to tell how many LOC that is. @EricPostpischil

Comment: @Barmar: I do not want to answer. The point was not to answer OP’s question but to show them they should not be thinking about code that way. And you can see how many lines of code it is, and I said how many lines it is.

Comment: @user16217248 While this may be on-topic on CR, in the future, please don't use the existence of the Code Review site as a reason to close a question. Evaluate the request and use a reason like *Needs more focus*, *primarily opinion-based*, etc. Then you can mention to the OP that it can be posted on Code Review if it is [on-topic](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic). Please see [_Does being on-topic at another Stack Exchange site automatically make a question off-topic for Stack Overflow?_](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/287400/1575353)

Comment: Code review is not an option.  I'm a user of stackoverflow and nothing more.  They've muddied the water with forcing people to other sites (even if they think it's their own).

Answer (score 3):

The following code prints a bunch of characters:

```
for (int z = row; z >= 0; z--)
{
    printf("#");
}
```

You can do it with a single `printf` call by cleverly indexing a string:

```
printf("##########" + 10 - (row + 1));
```

Here `"##########" + 10` is a pointer past the end of a string; subtracting a number from it will make a string containing that number of characters.

---

Instead of printing the end-of-line character explicitly, you can use `puts` which does that. Not sure this counts as simplification though, because you can't do that everywhere — it's just a funny fact.

---

You can output any number of spaces (but not other characters — this idea only works with spaces) by abusing the "field width" feature of `printf`. For example, the following will print a 4-character string in a 10-character field, effectively prepending 6 spaces to it:

```
printf("%*s", 10, "####");
```

This will make your code a little more complicated, but shorter. Not sure if the combined effect is an improvement. In any case, if you use such tricks, you must explain them in comments.

---

For extreme simplification, consider hard-coding your output strings. Since there are only a few possibilities for valid input, you can prepare all possible outputs as strings in code and output them immediately, without any calculations:

```
switch (height)
{
case 1: puts("..."); break;
case 2: puts("....."); break;
case 3: puts("......."); break;
...
}
```

Less fun though.

---

@chqrlie: Using the `printf` `%s` format with variable *width* and *precision* fields, here is a modified version:

```
#include <cs50.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void) {
    static char hashes[] = "########";
    int height = 0;
    // prompt for pos int between 1-8
    do {
        height = get_int("Height? ");
    } while (height < 1 || height > 8);

    for (int row = 1; row <= height; row++) {
        printf("%*.*s %.*s\n", height, row, hashes, row, hashes);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: I hope you don't mind my illustrating your proposed directions.

Comment: I prefer presenting only ideas so OP would have an opportunity to play around with them and do some debugging. Your code introduces another idea (the one with `%.*s`), so it's useful. But presenting it as part of working code spoils the fun (for my concept of fun).

Comment: s/abusing/using/

Comment: Instead of the `switch` statement I would use an array.